# PHP: is it possible to end a script like exit() but from inside a php class/object

Tags: php, class, object, exit

Is it possible to do this?

```
$objetc -> runAndFinish();

echo "this should not be echoed";
```

instead of this?

```
$objetc -> runAndFinish();

exit();

echo "this should not be echoed";
```

So runAndFinish(); method would somehow end the script processing.
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Just put the `exit();` or `die();` statement into the `runAndFinish()` method. Did you even try this before you asked the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put an exit(); inside of your classes runAndFinish(); method

```
class someClass{
  function runAndFinish(){
     exit();
  }
}

$obj = new someClass();
$obj->runAndFinish();
echo "not gonna print";
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the exit call in the method and it will exit during its call

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a class you can use:

```
if($condition)
{
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it's possible. It you put `exit()` or `die()` (or something else that might end execution) in that particular method and it will execute.

To my knowledge, there aren't any special restrictions for what you can execute in a methods vs. anything else.